# Use of a 'where' clause on a calculated field value

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, filter

I have a query for calculating the minimal price. The select statement part is:

```
IF(at_price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(at_price_index.min_price, at_price_index.tier_price), at_price_index.min_price) AS theprice
```

How can I add the following `where` clause?

```
where theprice = 10
```

I have tried the following code:

```
$myProductCollection->addFieldToFilter('theprice', '10');
```

But I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$myProductCollection->getSelect()->having('theprice = ?', 10);
```